# How to correctly import Gridstack using npm/webpack?

Tags: webpack, gridstack

I used npm to install gridstack library.

I was previously using gridstack as a standard js library but I want to include it now using npm/webpack instead of directly including it by myself. 
I don't understand what I need to include to make it working.

I was also using the release v1.1, what are the needed dependencies ? only gridstack or you also need jquery-ui ?

Main.js

```
import Gridstack from 'gridstack' //what I need to put here ?

var grid = Gridstack.init();
console.log(grid);
```

Package.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "@babel/polyfill": "^7.8.3",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.8.7",
    "gridstack": "^1.1.0",
 },
"devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.8.4",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "^7.8.3",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.8.3",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.8.4",
    "autoprefixer": "^8.6.4",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.6",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.0",
    "webpack": "^4.41.6",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.11"
  },
```

For the moment I have the following error :

```
TypeError: gridstack__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_7___default.a.init is not a function
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this now works in just released 1.2.1 (see release notes)

```
import 'jquery';
import 'jquery-ui';

import 'gridstack/dist/gridstack-poly'; // optional IE support
import GridStack from 'gridstack';
import 'gridstack/dist/gridstack.jQueryUI';
import 'gridstack/dist/gridstack.css';
```

but recommend you just use 2.x (native typescript re-write) which only needs this:

```
import { GridStack, $ } from 'gridstack'; // $ optional if you depend on it, to be removed in 3.x
import 'gridstack/dist/gridstack.css';
```

might want to also see
https://github.com/gridstack/gridstack.js#jquery-application

Answer (score 0):

A hack I found that works for me is importing gridstack as follows:

```
import 'gridstack/dist/jquery';
import 'gridstack/dist/gridstack';
import 'gridstack/dist/jquery-ui';
import 'gridstack/dist/gridstack.jQueryUI';
```

There is also a related [open issue](https://github.com/gridstack/gridstack.js/issues/1243) that discusses this problem.

Comment: Thank's for your answer. For the moment I use the CDN version because there is an issue with the TypeScript project (the one you use when importing from NPM). I mark your solution as the answer because the import works but maybe other people seeing this will need to wait for a stable version for npm stuff